# File is used by another process Cassandra

Tags: c#, cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I am using Cassandra 2.0.11 in Windows 7. I have a cql file that contains more than 40 table creation queries and I'm executing it from C# using a `System.Diagnostics.Process`. I am using the process to call cqlsh batch script in order to run this command : `cqlsh -f file.cql host`

I am having this exception:

```
ERROR [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2017-06-16 12:50:38,461 CassandraDaemon.java (line 199) Exception in thread Thread[NonPeriodicTasks:1,5,main]
FSWriteError in ...\system\schema_columnfamilies\system-schema_columnfamilies-jb-42-Index.db
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.deleteWithConfirm(FileUtils.java:122)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.deleteWithConfirm(FileUtils.java:108)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTable.delete(SSTable.java:145)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableDeletingTask.run(SSTableDeletingTask.java:86)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: ...\system\schema_columnfamilies\system-schema_columnfamilies-jb-42-Index.db: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.deleteWithConfirm(FileUtils.java:118)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: why are you not showing the relevant code as it pertains to the issue you are experiencing..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue (and a few others) is what was preventing Cassandra from running properly on Windows prior to version 3.x.  Windows doesn't like multiple processes accessing the same file simultaneously.

Essentially, you have two choices here:

- Upgrade Cassandra to (at least) 3.10.  Of course, you can't do a straight upgrade from 2.0 to 3.x, so you would need to upgrade to 2.1 first.  The 2.0 line reached its end-of-life a while ago, so upgrading is something you should consider, anyway.
- Run Cassandra on Linux.  While 3.x is finally supported on Windows, Cassandra on Windows is still a very new thing.  Your best chance for running a successful cluster (still) is to run it on Linux.